# Query Parse to get state of object

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am developing a social application using parse. I have following data models for parse.com

**User**

- name (String)
- email (String)
- ...

**Post**

- tittle (String)
- description (String)
- User (Pointer)
- Like (Pointer)
- Comment (Pointer)
- LikeCount (Number)
- Comment Count (Number)

**Like**

- User (Pointer)
- Post (Pointer)

**Comments**

- text (String)
- User (Pointer)
- Post (Pointer)

Now when I fetch posts I also want to fetch additional information which is

1. **If current user liked this post?**
2. **If current user commented on this
   post?**

I am wondering If I can get all these info in one network call. I don't want to perform multiple network calls for each post.

Answer (score 0):

In your query for fetching the post, you can indicate that you want the query to return also the related objects, like this:

```
...
query.include("User");
query.include("Like");
query.include("Comment");
```

or even

```
query.include("Like.User");
```

to get the Like object AND the User object related to that Like object

This will ensure that you get the full objects; not just the pointers to them.

However, these queries quickly become complex. I recommend you read the Parse tutorial for the Anypic app, and see how they have solved this. Anypic is for iOS only, but you should be able to understand the concepts.
https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic

Comment: Thanks for you time , I have already seen anypic. Any pic is fetch list of post items 1st and then again send request to fetch related information. I want to avoid that